# EPPLUS excel creation with date format on C#

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, date-format, epplus

I set custom date format(dd-MMM-yyyy) in excel via EPPlus code is not working, when the first record of date column(ex. D2 (DeliveryDate) ).

```
ws.Column(ColumnNumber).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
```

Comment: That works  for me.  Is the data being stored numeric and not strings?

Comment: It is stored as SQL Datetime, Getting from SQL DB only.

Comment: But how is it stored in excel when you write to the cells?  Might want to post more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

"dd-MMM-yyyy" isn't always a valid Excel date format, its not on my machine set to Australian English.
In excel date time formats are all lowercase. Presumably excel distinguishes between Month and minute by context.
[Create a custom date or time format](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/format-numbers-as-dates-or-times-418bd3fe-0577-47c8-8caa-b4d30c528309#bm2)

So  "dd-mmm-yyyy" will work
But "dd-MMM-yyyy" will not (always) work.